# vue-authenticate not working on mobile browser: callback opens new tab breaking flow

Tags: vue.js, authentication, redirect, mobile, vue-authenticate

I'm using **vue-authenticate** for social account authentication. It works perfectly on desktop browsers, but not android mobile (chrome/firefox).

When authenticating, the popup window opens and works correctly, but then the redirectUri (with the access token) opens in a **new browser tab** (not the origin tab), therefore losing state and breaking the auth flow.

How to work around this? thx

https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Is it still valid in the last release?